# Error : "Language is already enabled or invalid! " in wordpress plugin qTranslate

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

When trying to enable newly added language in **qTranslate Configuration ** I get a message
**Language is already enabled or invalid!**

All the languages that come with qTranslate are ok.
Wordpress 3.13

Any ideas? thanx

Comment: This is a *user support*, Plugin-specific question, that would be better-directed to the [qTranslate Plugin support forum](http://wordpress.org/tags/qtranslate?forum_id=10).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution and described it here:

http://shtrak.eu/vloo/tech/language-is-already-enabled-or-invalid-when-enablin-new-language-to-qtranslate/

Watch out for older database converters that might wipe out your content!